# Return page reference with if statements

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I'm wondering how to call new pagereference with if conditional statements, here is my controller;

```
public with sharing class TargetController{


    //Set up all getter and setter method
    public String selectedTarget {get;set;} 

    PageReference homepage = new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');

    //Select option list that will be shown in the visualforce page
    List<SelectOption> selTargetType = new List<selectOption>();


    public List<SelectOption> getselTargetType(){

        selTargetType.add( new SelectOption('COLLECTION TARGET', 'Collection'));
        selTargetType.add( new SelectOption('SIGNED REVENUE TARGET', 'SignedRevenue'));
        selTargetType.add( new SelectOption('NETWORK TARGET', 'NetworkTarget'));
        return selTargetType;
    }


    public PageReference applyTarget() {

        IF(selectedTarget == 'COLLECTION TARGET' ){
            Pagereference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/CollectionTargetSettingInit');
            /*pageref.getParameters().put('custoemrlocation','TX');*/
        }

        IF(selectedTarget == 'SIGNED REVENUE TARGET' ){
            Pagereference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/SignedRevenueTargetPeriodSetting');
            /*pageref.getParameters().put('custoemrlocation','TX');*/
        }

        IF(selectedTarget == 'NETWORK TARGET' ){
            Pagereference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/networkTargetSettingInit');
           /* pageref.getParameters().put('custoemrlocation','TX');*/
        }

        return pageRef;
    }

}
```

I want simply use the returned value from get;set `selectedTarget` method as the parameter to determine what page should be called in the `applyTarget` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would code that like this:

```
public PageReference applyTarget() {

    String url;
    switch on selectedTarget {
        when 'COLLECTION TARGET' {
            url = '/apex/CollectionTargetSettingInit';
        }
        when 'SIGNED REVENUE TARGET' {
            url = '/apex/SignedRevenueTargetPeriodSetting';
        }
        when 'NETWORK TARGET' {
            url = '/apex/networkTargetSettingInit';
        }
        when else {
            url = null;
        }
    }

    if (url != null) {
        // Go to next page
        Pagereference pageRef = new PageReference(url);
        pageref.getParameters().put('custoemrlocation','TX');
        return pageRef;
    } else {
        // Leave the user on the current page
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith, this worked for me thanks!!!